# Need a simple tool for analysing unicode characters

Tags: unicode, text, special-characters, character, identify

I'm surprised I can't find a simple tool for this. Basically, sometimes as a result of text munging, or using some piece of software, I end up with some text that has some troublesome characters - such as looking a lot like other characters, but being distinct from them. I'd like a tool (preferably online, javascript based) where I can paste the text, and it will tell me all the characters involved, their names, unicode codes etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Unicode Character Search](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm)

Edit: Sorry, missed the part where you wanted to search multiple characters at a time. Try this:
http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/

This might also be what you're looking for:
http://rishida.net/scripts/uniview/uniview.php

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommand to use from open source Unicode Converter at http://unicode.codeplex.com , this tool will give you complete information of each character and vice versa.